# Rails activeRecord raw sql to diffent schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-6

I use public schema in my rails app(postgresql) and then I imported some data from pgdump to different schema.

When I try to select that different schema with ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute, I get ok status, but zero records, even query works fine in DB. When I do the same for any table from base public schema, all works well.

I added to database.yml

```
schema_search_path: "public,customschema"
```

but doesnt help, still no records, no error when I query that schema

where else should I look/enable access to that schema?

Comment: query is simple select two columns from two tables joined with inner join

tables exists only in customschema, not in public

I tried also create view in public schema with this query and I cannot see result either in rails, but in postgres I can query that view without any problem